# Why are links to www.mariowiki.com not allowed?

Tags: support

When attempting to answer the question [Do Shadow People Exist?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/189488/do-shadow-people-exist), I found some valid-looking information on www.mariowiki.com. After I linked to it in my answer I wasn't allowed to submit, with an error message saying "links to www.mariowiki.com are not allowed".

Why is this? The website looks no better or worse (in terms of quality/correctness) than many others I've seen linked to.

Comment: I'd suspect that they have spammed in the past, that is by far the most common reason to blacklist a URL.

Comment: @MadScientist Mariowiki it's not in /admin/blacklist for what it's worth.

Comment: @badp huh, I don't remember any other mechanism that would block specific links

Comment: @MadScientist Does that list include network-wide blacklists?

Answer (score 5):

We don't have any explicit blacklisting on mariowiki. However, it may be possible that the URL you're trying to use [may contain bogus characters such as HTML entities](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258765/links-to-my-own-website-not-allowed). That would produce that same error message. If you could post the URL you attempted within code formatting using backticks, that would allow us to examine it.

Comment: That's interesting - I am fairly sure I didn't include any encoded characters but I don't recall the exact URL I tried to post. I just tried to post a similar URL and it worked, so I've deleted the answer (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/189741/8090). Is there a way to test things like this, e.g. a 'sandbox' question/answer?